# Creating Barcode to "Alt+Tab" and switching windows application, and Enter Key

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, hotkeys, alt-tab

I would like to ask for some help with firstly how to define the windows keys "Alt+Tab" and "Enter" key when using an online barcode generator like https://barcode.tec-it.com/en. Alternatively, if there isn't a way to define the keyboard commands, is there a place that I can find these commands in the form of Barcodes? Code-128 is preferred.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Barcodes simply contain ASCII (or with more modern 2d symbols) UTF-8 character codes.  So standard keyboard values such as Enter and Tab that correspond to ASCII values can be encoded in a barcode.

On the other hand, dedicated barcode scanners that attach via USB are essentially keyboard emulators.  And those can be programmed to create Alt and Ctrl key sequences.

Unfortunately, I do not know of any scanner makers that support Alt-Tab.  Most programmable scanners can create Alt-A ... Alt-Z but not Alt-Tab.

Additionally, most barcode scanners allow you to define prefix and suffix key codes to send when a barcode is scanned.  The most common configuration is to send Enter or Tab after each scanned barcode.  This is done by programming the scanner, not in the barcode.